# Writing a program for a running competition using array

Tags: java

> Write a program that asks for the names of three runners and the time, in minutes, it took each of them to finish a race. The program should display the names of the runners in the order that they finished.

The program works for whole numbers but is unable to arrange decimals. If I change the variable to integers, the input causes an error. Is there a solution for this?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

    class Runners implements Comparable<Runners> {
        public String name;
        public double time;
        
        public Runners(String name, double time) {
            this.name = name;
            this.time = time;    
        }

        public String toString() {
            return String.format(" %s: %.2f minute(s) ", name, time);
        }

        public int compareTo(Runners other) {
            return (int) (this.time - other.time);
        }
    }
```

```
public class Question2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 3;
        Runners[] runnersData = new Runners[count];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter runner's name and time taken in minutes: ");
            runnersData[i] = new Runners(input.next().strip(), input.nextDouble());
        }
        input.close();
        Arrays.sort(runnersData);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(runnersData));
    }
}
```

The unsorted decimals:
[image: The unsorted decimals]

The error if changed to int:
[image: The error if changed to int]

Comment: If you're asking about an error, best to post the input and the complete error message.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry for the rollback, I didn't notice what effect that html comment had.

Comment: When you say "unable to **arrange** decimals", what do you mean by "arrange"?

Comment: The error posts should be posted as code-formatted text, not as an image. Please go through the [help] to see how to best use this site, how to make it easier to answer your questions.

Comment: By "unable to **arrange** decimals", I mean it just prints the names according to the input order like in the image

Comment: Are you using `input.nextInt()` and feeding the Scanner a double value?

Answer (score 3):

`compareTo` doesn't require you to return the results of your arithmetic. You only have to return an integer signifying whether the items are equal, greater or less than.

```
public int compareTo(Runners other) {
    if(this.time == other.time)
       return 0;
    else if(this.time > other.time)
       return 1;
    else 
       return -1;
}
```

See the documentation on `compareTo` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)). Also be aware that comparing doubles won't always behave the way you expect. I added the above for an example usage, but you can probably just return `Double.compareTo(d1, d2)`. See [those docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare-double-double-).

Comment: Also worth mentioning that OP's solution didn't work because the cast to `int` turns something like `6.7 - 6.1 = 0.6` into `6.7 - 6.1 = 0` which discards the information which number was bigger.

Comment: Thanks, both solutions worked out great. I completely looked over that.